# thinkpad touchpad keeps turning off and on at random

Tags: laptop, mouse, linux-mint, touchpad, thinkpad

I bought my [Lenovo thinkpad T440s](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t440s/documentation)   (running the latest version of linux mint) secondhand a couple of months ago, and it has been working fine except the last two days. **My touchpad stops responding, and I have to use an external mouse to move the cursor.** It suddenly stopped working saturday night, started working again sunday morning, and stopped working an hour ago.

The weird part? saturday night I disabled the touchpad in the BIOS, and it's been disabled this whole time, even though the touchpad was working fine until about an hour ago.

Edit: No, the touchpad does not work even when booting from a live USB. I re-installed Linux Mint, and then tried Ubuntu, and still no luck.

I've read several forms and threads, and none of them have been able to help me. Any replies are deeply appreciated.

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/ and https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ may be helpful. Also, as a simple diagnostic, does the touchpad work OK if you boot from a LiveUSB?